# Android Issue with Resource after upgrade.

Tags: android, resources, drawable, google-play

I have an app, and stupid me decided to change a resource in the file from being filename.bmp to being a png, and released an upgrade with this, I removed the .bmp from the APK and added the PNG, and placed it on the marketplace.

Now, I have some users who are not able to run the app, it is failing with a file not found on the line referencing the resource name in the VIEW XML description.

Now, it is only some users, not all.. but its still infuriating, when a suer upgrades, are the old APK files removed? IE is the old .BMP file gone?  I have been unable to fully replicated the problem on my equipment, but I am working off the theory that the .BMP and the .PNG file are now both in the resource/drawable directory and the XML inflate is just getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to rename the files BMP and PNG to completely different names. This could cause confusion though.

I would recommend using one file type for all applications. And it may be that some user's are not experiencing the issue is because of screen density. Make sure all of the resources use the same naming convention and are availible for each screen size.

Comment: I am trying renaming the resource in the latest release, in fact had already put that in the market before asking the question, I was hoping for some confirmation that my theory might be correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file to something completely different.

Comment: I am trying this in the latest release, even before I posted the question, but I wanted to verify if this might be the culprit.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned the project and rebuilt.. I can't replicate this issue, and its not happening on all devices.  I renamed the file fixed the references in the XML for the new file and still users are getting this error.. I am beyond confused... and very frustrated.

Comment: It keeps dying RES.Resource$NotFoundException: File from Drawable resource ID #0X1020004

Comment: The only thing I see that seems weird is there is no resource with that # in the generated R.java code, it references #0X7f0200009 for the image that the line of the XML is dying on inflate, there are no resources with #0x1... anything... so I don't know what the heck is going on or why.  Its not all devices, or users.. but its clearly happening and I am not able to replicate it so I have no idea what is going on.